# Save and Restore TextView Data

Tags: android, textview

I have an activity with several TextView elements which include some buttons.  When a button for a specific set of TextView elements is clicked a new activity is started to enter some data.  This data is then returned to the specific TextView elements.

My problem is that when I select another button for different set of TextView elements, the new activity appears to enter the data and the new data returns to the main activity, but the previously entered data is gone.

How do I keep previously entered data from being removed?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I keep previously entered data from being removed?

```
<TextView 
 ... 
 android:freezesText="true" />
```

From documentation on [freezes text:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3afreezesText)

> If set, the text view will include its current complete text inside of its frozen icicle in addition to meta-data such as the current cursor position. By default this is disabled; it can be useful when the contents of a text view is not stored in a persistent place such as a content provider.